# What to Roll against with innate attack

Tags: magic, gurps-4e

I am currently reading GURPS Magic. I want to use Thaumatology ritual path magic and have run into a problem. When using missile spells you have to roll against Innate Attack but how do I determine that value?

Comment: @DennisChristian please don't answer in comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to throw Missile Spells you use the Skill Innate Attack with the Missile specialization, likewise there is a Beam specialization for Beam Spells.

You find the Skill Description in the Basic Set.

Comment: Comment deleted.

Comment: Well I tried looking in basic set but only found an advantage. Thanks though.

Comment: Innate Attack is a skill (with multiple sub-entries).  Don't have my books with me at work, but it's alphabetically located in the Skills section of Basic Set: Characters.

Comment: I found it by coincidence the other day thanks a lot. you really helped me out. :)

Answer (score 2):

For spells like Fireball, Lightning, Ice Missile, and Stone Missile, which innate attack to use is explicit. If this isn't the case for your Ritual Path Magic (built like a Power, as I recall), double check with your GM -- though as a GM, I'd rule that it should use the innate attack that makes sense. If the ritual creates a missile, it'd use the "Innate Attack, Missile" skill; if it creates something that acts like a beam, you'd use "Innate Attack, Beam", etc. Note also that these might have an Acc bonus (the ones for the spells I listed do) that applies if you Aim